# MVC3 and JQuery - Can JQuery ajax method display an image generated in the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

Is it possible to use the JQuery ajax method to pass parameters into a controller, have the action in the controller return an image and display that image back to the user?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Controller/Action',
    data: { 'parameter1': '\'' + parameter1Value + '\'', 'parameter2': '\'' + parameter1Value + '\'', 'parameter3': '\'' + parameter1Value },
    dataType: 'image' /* Can ajax return an image? */,
    success: function (imageResults) {
        // Do something
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

My goal is to generate a dynamic image based on parameters in the form and display that image back to the user.  In addtion, ad added bonus would be to fire the ajaxstart and ajaxstop handling used by other ajax calls on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't AJAX controller actions that return images or files or something. A much easier solution is the following:

```
$('body').append(
    $('<img/>', {
        src: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")?parameter1=' + encodeURIComponent(parameter1Value) + '&parameter2=' + encodeURIComponent(parameter2Value),
        alt: 'some image'
    })
);
```

This simply dynamically injects the following `<img>` tag to the end of the `<body>` (you could of course adapt the location if you don't like the body):

```
<img src="/Controller/Action/?parameter1=foo&parameter2=bar" alt="some image" />
```

The browser will do the rest. Just ensure that the controller action returns a `File` result.

Also if those images are dynamically generated each time, IE could cause certain PITAs as it might cache them. To bust the cache append a random timestamp to the url:

```
$('body').append(
    $('<img/>', {
        src: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")?parameter1=' + encodeURIComponent(parameter1Value) + '&parameter2=' + encodeURIComponent(parameter2Value) + '&cacheBuster=' + encodeURIComponent((new Date()).getTime()),
        alt: 'some image'
    })
);
```

Comment: Excellent.  Works like a charm - the only problem is that the ajaxstop doesn't seem to want to fire.

Comment: @Andy Evans, `ajaxstop`? There is no AJAX involved whatsoever when you want to display an image.

Comment: Can you please write controller code? I just don't want to use ajax. I created an Img element and assigned wanted Src URL that is by default get. But it cannot render image. However when i put same in ajax and return Base64 string from controller then it works. Can anybody tell me why i cannot directly write Source url that returns base64 response?